# Problema con javascript y formularios

Tags: javascript, formularios

tengo un problema con este codigo, la idea seria que cuando toque el boton "submit" me muestre abajo los datos cargados en el formulario

```
<!-- Formulario -->
<div class="formulario">
    <h1> Tienda offline </h1>

    <form name="cargar" method="get" action="cargar.html">
        <p>Nombre:<input type="text" class="nombre"
        name="producname"></p>
        <p>Precio:<input type="text" class="precio" name="price"></p>
        <p>ID:<input type="text" class="id" name="identify"></p>
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="Añadir producto" class="boton1" id="addproducto" onclick="cargar">
        <input type="submit" name="mod" value="Modificar producto" class="boton1"
        id="modproducto">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="java">

</div>

<script>

    var nombre, identify, precio;

    function cargar() {
        var nombre = document.forms.cargar.producname.value;
        identify = document.forms.cargar.identify.value;
        precio = document.forms.cargar.price.value;

        document.getElementById('java').innerHTML =
        `
            <div>
                <p>$nombre;</p>
                <p>$identify;</p>
                <p>$precio;</p>
            </div>
        `
    }

</script>
```

La idea seria que me muestre los valores cargados en la misma pagina

Comment: Juan para juntar perfiles de usuarios (el de tu pregunta y el de tu comentario en la publicacion de Shadow) lee https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3430/vincular-a-mi-cuenta-de-usuario-una-pregunta-que-hice-como-invitado/3431#3431

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que hagas lo siguiente:

1. En lugar de un botón `submit` mejor un `button` para evitar el comportamiento por defecto de `submit` que sería recargar la página web
2. el botón lo obtenemos por medio de JS a través de su `id`
3. a la `var` que contiene el acceso al botón le asignamos un `handler` en el evento `click` para que cada que se presente este evento la función que va por dentro se active
4. Por dentro obtenemos cada `input`y los imprimimos concatenandolo
5. El `handler` que recibe 2 parámetros, uno es el evento y otro es la función

*CÓDIGO*

```
 <form name="cargar" method="get" action="cargar.html">
        <p>Nombre:<input type="text" class="nombre"
        id="producname"></p>
        <p>Precio:<input type="text" class="precio" id="price"></p>
        <p>ID:<input type="text" class="id" id="identify"></p>
        <input type="button" id="add" value="Añadir producto">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="java">

</div>

<script>
    let btn = document.querySelector("#add")
    btn.addEventListener("click", function cargar() {
        let nombre = document.querySelector("#producname").value
        let price = document.querySelector("#price").value
        let identify = document.querySelector("#identify").value

        document.querySelector('#java').innerHTML = nombre+' '+price+' '+identify
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias shadow! me solucionaste todo el código, me había olvidado que submit refrescaba la pagina

Comment: Hola @Juan recuerda que si esta respuesta soluciono la problematica expuesta en tu pregunta, puedes marcarla como aceptada, revisa [tour] , saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo (funcional) de como hacerlo tratando en lo posible hacer cambios (mínimos) a tu código.

```js
function cargar_add() {
 var nombre = document.forms.cargar.producname.value,
 identify = document.forms.cargar.identify.value,
 precio = document.forms.cargar.price.value;
 document.getElementById("java").innerHTML = '<div><p>'+nombre+'</p><p>'+identify+'</p><p>'+precio+'</p></div>'
}
```

```html
<!-- Formulario -->
<div class="formulario">
    <h1> Tienda offline </h1>

    <form name="cargar" method="get" action="cargar.html">
        <p>Nombre:<input type="text" class="nombre"
        name="producname"></p>
        <p>Precio:<input type="text" class="precio" name="price"></p>
        <p>ID:<input type="text" class="id" name="identify"></p>
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="Añadir producto" class="boton1" id="addproducto" onclick="cargar_add();return false;">
        <input type="submit" name="mod" value="Modificar producto" class="boton1"
        id="modproducto">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="java">

</div>
```